# Set first bootstrap card (item) as active

Tags: php, html, css

I'm using carousel to display data from database and I tried to set first card active but it won't work and cards are static. Cards works fine without php. I was trying to use boolean variable and set active class with some conditions but it didn't work.

```
      <div id="recipeCarousel" class="carousel slide w-100" data-ride="carousel">
        <div class="carousel-inner w-100" role="listbox">
          <?php
           require_once('connect/dbConnection.php');
           $query  = "SELECT * FROM table_cards";
           $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);

           while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                $image = 'uploads/'.$row['images'];
                $isFirst = True;
                if ($isFirst == True) {
                $isFirst == False;
            ?>
            <div class="carousel-item active" data-interval="2000">
              <?php
            } else {
              ?>
            <div class="carousel-item" data-interval="2000">
            <?php } ?>
            <div class="col-md-4">
              <div class="card">
                <img class="card-img-top" src="<?php echo $image; ?>" alt="Card image cap">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <h5 class="card-title"><?php echo $row['name']; ?></h5>
                  <p class="card-text text-left"><i class="fas fa-ruler-combined"></i> <strong>Size</strong>: <?php echo $row['size']; ?><br> <i class="fas fa-money-bill-wave"></i> <strong>Price</strong>: <?php echo $row['price']; ?><br><i class="fas fa-home"></i> <strong>House type</strong>: <?php echo $row['house_type']; ?><br><br><i class="fas fa-bed"></i> <?php echo $row['bed']; ?><i class="fas fa-toilet"></i> <?php echo $row['toilet']; ?></p>
                  <a href="gallery.html#first-post" class="stretched-link"></a>
                </div>
                <div class="card-footer">
                  <small class="text-muted">Lorem</small>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        <?php } ?>
        </div>
        <a class="carousel-control-prev w-auto" href="#recipeCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
          <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon bg-dark border border-dark rounded-circle" aria-hidden="true"><i class="fas fa-angle-left fa-2x carousel-icon mr-1"></i></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a class="carousel-control-next w-auto" href="#recipeCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
          <span class="carousel-control-next-icon bg-dark border border-dark rounded-circle" aria-hidden="true"><i class="fas fa-angle-right fa-2x carousel-icon ml-1"></i></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>
      </div>
     </div>
```

Comment: Have you got any php/console error output

Comment: Everything is working on php  and database side there's a problem with setting active class on first carousel card.

Comment: Is it setting every single card to active?

Comment: Yes it sets every card as active

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting `$isFirst = True` and then set it in condition to false in **each** while loop, where's the sense? Change it to:

```php
$isFirst = true;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $image = 'uploads/'.$row['images'];

    your HTML here
    <div class="carousel-item <?php echo ($isFirst)? 'active':'' ?>" data-interval="2000">


    $isFirst = false;
} // end of loop
```

Answer (score 1):

> Yes it sets every card as active

because you tell it to.

```
$isFirst = True;
if ($isFirst == True) {
   $isFirst = False;
```

you set `$isFirst` to true on every pass in the loop.  You need a check here to test if it's already set

//EDIT

Actually you should move `$isFirst = True;` outside the loop

```
$isFirst = True;

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $image = 'uploads/'.$row['images'];
      if ($isFirst == True) {
        $isFirst = False;
```